# not able to checkin or undo checkout

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a file in clearcase checked out. But I am not able to do checkin or undo checkout. It says
"To operate on UCM branch, must be set to an activity and a UCM view."

When i try to checkin, it does not show the activity set in the view . so, i selected the activity manually and tried checkin. It gave same error.
I cannot delete the view and create a new one as there are other checkouts which should not be affetected. I tried going to the view from command line and cleartool setact .still undocheckout or checkin gives same error.please advise

Comment: What is your ClearCase client OS and version?

Answer (score 0):

Check your cleartool status to see if there is a way to explain your current view state.

You should still be able to set an activity with [cleartool setact](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setactivity.htm)

```
 cleartool setact anExistingActivty@\aPvob
```

If not, try and create a new activity first, before setting it (with [`cleartool mkact`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkactivity.htm))

> To operate on UCM branch, must be set to an activity and a UCM view

Make sure your view is an UCM view:

```
cd /path/to/my/view
cleartool catcs
```

You should see UCM in the config spec.

Comment: It's all clear case 8. I tried already to setact by using a old activity and also by creating a new activity. It's the same error. For other files I can see the set activity coming automatically during checking but not for this particular file.

Comment: @user2636464 what is your OS? What error message do you see?

Comment: Windows 7 To operate on UCM branch, must be set to an activity and a UCM view."

Comment: @user2636464 What error message do you see when you try and set an activity, or make a new one?

Comment: @user2636464 and when you are using that new activity with setact?

Comment: No error . Only it is coming with check-in and undo checkout

Answer (score 0):

@user2636464 @VonC There are a number of PVOB/CVOB issues that can lead to this, and all I can do is ask questions.

1. If you create another view on the same stream, can you check out other files in the same directory as the problem directory?
2. Are there other checked-out files in the same component with the same issue?
3. If you describe the checked out version, is there a "Change" hyperlink?
4. How long has this file been checked out? Has anything happened in the environment -- particularly to the PVOB -- since the checkout occurred?

There are some PVOB/CVOB database issues that can lead to things like this, and you may be best served by contacting IBM/HCL. You will likely be sent a stream_data.pl script that will need to be run to collect information about the stream/component containing the "stuck" checkout.

Final (unrelated) note: ClearCase 8.x went out of support at COB yesterday. I would recommend moving to 9.0.1.3 at your earliest convenience.

Comment: If you create another view on the same stream, can you check out other files in the same directory as the problem directory? YES.even the other files using the same view
Are there other checked-out files in the same component with the same issue? no
If you describe the checked out version, is there a "Change" hyperlink? yes
How long has this file been checked out? Has anything happened in the environment -- particularly to the PVOB -- since the checkout occurred?- nothing changed.

Comment: @user2636464 Please open a case with IBM/HCL as the diagnostic tools aren't freely available.